# Review this, now!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> What's happening is very strange,
>   I belong to another StackExchange!
>
> I'm indeed off-topic here in Puzzling,
>   It isn't always clear what I'm saying.
>
> Even though I'm often too broad,
>   Review it, something is flawed.
>
> I'm just suggesting an edit,
>   A low quality job, ain't it?
>
> For new users I'm a big trouble
>   A duplicate isn't always a double.
>
> Your current work you shall reopen
>   Flag here, flag there, it's all broken!
>
> Oh, don't forget to add a comment,
>   late it's not, takes just a moment!

**What am I?**

**Hint #1:**

> I'm sometimes cause and consequence of inappropriate language"

**Hint #2:**

> Upvoted or downvoted, doesn't matter, I generally appear in the bottom.

**Hint #3:**

> I notify you to review something.

Comment: sounds interesting !!!!.. .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's hilarious.

Comment: @IanMacDonald It's intended to be a funny "background", but this is a serious riddle, with a serious answer.

Comment: I know. It's not a serious close vote, it's just there for added effect.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Ahah, good one!

Comment: I'd like to know whom downvoted this. Why? I mean, this riddle has a funny theme and rhymes, doesn't look so bad I hope.

Comment: @leoll2 I think someone is going around today giving out free down votes. Just ignore it as this seems to be a good riddle!

Comment: @leoll2 Mark N and i had the same problem on one of his questions. seems like someone is grumpy

Comment: Some people just hate riddles on principle, e.g. see [here](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=2902355#2902355) (VLQ = Very Low Quality). Don't let it get to you :-)

Comment: I only hate riddles when I can't figure them out.       >.>    I hate riddles.  First answer that came to mind (kind of in the same spirit of things) is a Moron  >_<

Comment: @leoll2, is it spam? see my edited answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are an

> IDE Debugger

What's happening is very strange,
I belong to another StackExchange!

> Typically people would ask about problems found in the debugger on StackOverflow.

I'm indeed off-topic here in Puzzling,
It isn't always clear what I'm saying.

> Sometimes the error given is fairly vague and unhelpful.

Even though I'm often too broad,
Review it, something is flawed.

> The vague error message may be hard to interpret, but there is definitely something wrong that must be looked over.

I'm just suggesting an edit,
A low quality job, ain't it?

> The message is telling you to change something in the code.

For new users I'm a big trouble
A duplicate isn't always a double.

> Beginner programmers may have a hard time figuring out what the error is, especially when they've gotten the same error twice with a different cause.

Your current work you shall reopen
Flag here, flag there, it's all broken!

> Go back to your code, you need to check all the marked areas for bugs. Sometimes a single typo, like an extra or missing `}`, will cause huge amounts of code to be highlighted as 'broken'.

Oh, don't forget to add a comment,
late it's not, takes just a moment!

> When you fix the bug, add a comment to the code to make sure it is clear to others (or your future self) why the code is the way it is.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This is a very good answer for your first post. I hope that you can maintain a quality as high as this in many of your future posts here!

Comment: Oh oh! You're very close! The correct answer was actually "an error message", but you've interpreted all the lines correctly, so I accept this as best answer :-)

Comment: @MarkN Thanks! I have some experience using StackOverflow from my work account and have been lurking around puzzling for a couple months now.

Comment: @leoll2 That's pretty clever. I like the misdirection, making it seem like the answer is related to SE itself. I've been think everyone else's answers were so close for a week now.

Comment: @RootVegetable That's exactly what I tried to do, I'm glad you appreciated it :)

Answer (score 8):

You are a

> Closed question

What's happening is very strange, I belong to another StackExchange!

> Questions can be closed if they belong to a different SE.

I'm indeed off-topic here in Puzzling,

> Off-topic questions are closed.

It isn't always clear what I'm saying.

> Questions that are unclear are closed.

Even though I'm often too broad,

> Questions that are too broad are closed.

Review it, something is flawed.

> If a question is closed, it can be flagged to be reopened, in which case it enters the review queue.

I'm just suggesting an edit,

> Closed questions can be edited.

A low quality job, ain't it?

> Low quality questions can be closed.

For new users I'm a big trouble

> Closed questions can lead to a question ban, especially if you're a new user.

A duplicate isn't always a double.

> Sometimes questions closed as duplicates aren't actually duplicates.

Your current work you shall reopen, Flag here, flag there, it's all broken!

> If you can improve a closed question, you can flag to reopen it.

Oh, don't forget to add a comment, late it's not, takes just a moment!

> People can still comment on closed questions.

Comment: I think you nailed it :)

Comment: Nah, it's not a closed question! Good try!

Comment: @leoll2, i was going to answer codereview.SE but then i saw pacoverflow's answer which i thought was the correct one, should i still bother with my answer?

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat Nah, codereview isn't correct!

Comment: @leoll2 if this isn't the correct answer, your puzzle is too imprecise. Fix the puzzle, or mark this correct and make a new puzzle.

Comment: @IanMacDonald You aren't the one who decides if a solution is correct or not. Pac's answer fits quite well, but you probably noticed that I build my puzzle with SE review as main theme. Of course, this doesn't mean that the answer is related to SE! Open mind for a different view!

Answer (score 6):

I think I got it

> you are a bug :)

```
What's happening is very strange,
I belong to another StackExchange!
```

> when you have something weird on your code, you go on stackoverflow

```
I'm indeed off-topic here in Puzzling,
It isn't always clear what I'm saying.
```

> you don't post questions about bugs here. And sometime, it is hard to explain something we don't understand.

```
Even though I'm often too broad,
Review it, something is flawed.
```

> sometime the question is too vague to find it and usually we ask a review on a code to find it

```
I'm just suggesting an edit,
A low quality job, ain't it?
```

> answers are usually simple edits because people do not proof read

```
For new users I'm a big trouble
A duplicate isn't always a double.
```

> when you are new, it is hard to determine if the bug is a duplicate of something existing or not

```
Your current work you shall reopen
Flag here, flag there, it's all broken!
```

> To isolate it, you have to open your source code and add markers to isolate it until you find the broken part

```
Oh, don't forget to add a comment,
late it's not, takes just a moment!
```

> and always comment your bug so you don't do it again

Thanks to Spacemonkey, for inspiration

#### Edit

If you are not a bug, you are a

> bug report

Comment: Very very close! The answer isn't a bug, but you're very close!

Comment: @leoll2 I updated my answer with a new answer

Answer (score 5):

My answer is :

> Coding (review)

```
What's happening is very strange,
I belong to another StackExchange!
```

> Stackoverflowwwwwwwwww

```
I'm indeed off-topic here in Puzzling,
It isn't always clear what I'm saying.
```

> Obviously doesn't belong in Puzzling and to most people here (maybe) asking code questions would be unclear

```
Even though I'm often too broad,
Review it, something is flawed.
```

> Could refer to code or comments in code, allthough making it generic isnt bad, only in some cases.

```
I'm just suggesting an edit,
A low quality job, ain't it?
```

> A lot of code problems come from low quality work

```
For new users I'm a big trouble
A duplicate isn't always a double.
```

> Make sure you don't duplicate code. That being said a duplicate doesnt need to be an exact copy of something else (double), if it DOES the same thing, its a duplicate.

```
Your current work you shall reopen
Flag here, flag there, it's all broken!
```

> If you did break code you'll have to go re-work it because it'll be breaking all over the place (flags representing errors in some coding environments)

```
Oh, don't forget to add a comment,
late it's not, takes just a moment!
```

> The importance of commenting code.

Comment: Very very good answer, still not the exact one!

Comment: That's a good one. But it is probably "source code"!

Answer (score 2):

Let's try another answer (get some more activity back here). This is largely inspired by [your recent post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2971/lateral-thinking-requires-a-new-policy). Are you:

> A Lateral-Thinking Question

What's happening is very strange,
 I belong to another StackExchange!

> There is some thought of moving lateral-thinking to Area 51.

I'm indeed off-topic here in Puzzling,
 It isn't always clear what I'm saying.

> Some consider lateral-thinking questions to be off topic as they aren't always good puzzles.

Even though I'm often too broad,
 Review it, something is flawed.

> The main issue with lateral-thinking is that they are often so broad that there are so many answers it isn't even funny.

I'm just suggesting an edit,
 A low quality job, ain't it?

> Most lateral-thinking could be improved with a nice edit to narrow down the possibilities.

For new users I'm a big trouble
 A duplicate isn't always a double.

> A lot of new users seem to try lateral-thinking and get some downvotes. Also, a lot of lateral-thinking puzzles seem to be similar.

Your current work you shall reopen
 Flag here, flag there, it's all broken!

> They can be reopened if they are fixed.  A lot get flagged for deletion.

Oh, don't forget to add a comment,
 late it's not, takes just a moment!

> Most could be improved if they were commented on where the issue is.

Comment: Good attempt, but no! I'll add another hint soon

Answer (score 1):

You are:

> The review queue!

I belong to another stack exchange

> you belong to all the stack exchanges. They all have the review queue.

For everything else:

> These are all line items or pieces of a review-able item.

Comment: Nice try, but it's not!

Comment: Darn, thought I had it.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by (and very close to) pacoverflow's answer, but hopefully different enough:

> A flagged question

What's happening is very strange,
 I belong to another StackExchange!

> Questions can be flagged to be migrated to the appropriate section.

I'm indeed off-topic here in Puzzling,

> Off topic questions can be flagged for deletion. Also, many questions that would be considered "flaggable" (I take artistic license) on other sites would be fine here (answer known, not informative, etc.)

It isn't always clear what I'm saying.

> Questions that are too broad are often flagged.

Even though I'm often too broad,

> Same as before.

Review it, something is flawed.

> Flagged questions are reviewed to address some problem.

I'm just suggesting an edit,
 A low quality job, ain't it?

> Many flags are due to a need for an edit, possibly for low quality questions.

For new users I'm a big trouble

> New users don't want to be flagged and kicked. Also, they can scare new users away.

A duplicate isn't always a double.

> Sometimes flagged if it might be a duplicate, or to see if it is.

Your current work you shall reopen

> Closed questions can be flagged for review and potential reopening.

Flag here, flag there, it's all broken!

> Flags all around! You can only flag so many items in a time period.

Oh, don't forget to add a comment,
 late it's not, takes just a moment!

> Users appreciate a comment as to why their questions are flagged, or you need to add a comment when you flag for what should be looked at.

Comment: I like your plain answer, but the answer isn't this! Keep thinking!

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> a vote?

What's happening is very strange,
I belong to another StackExchange!
I'm indeed off-topic here in Puzzling,
It isn't always clear what I'm saying.

> In all of these cases you could down vote. Although, here also a flag would be the right answer.

Even though I'm often too broad,
Review it, something is flawed.
I'm just suggesting an edit,
A low quality job, ain't it?
For new users I'm a big trouble
A duplicate isn't always a double.

> Those definitely point more towards a flag. But a lot of people just down vote again.

Your current work you shall reopen
Flag here, flag there, it's all broken!

> As you mention a flag, it's not the flag. It's the vote to reopen a mistakenly flagged and closed question.

Oh, don't forget to add a comment,
late it's not, takes just a moment!

> If you vote (too often) without commenting, you are generally reminded by any SE site, that you should comment, too.

Comment: Good attempt, but it's not a vote!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about all kinds of actions you can do here I'll take a guess and think you are

> A question on the meta stackexchange http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Good attempt, but not the correct answer. There are many hints inside the text, find them!

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED ANSWER**

Yet I'm not sure, but guess is

> Spam Questions

?

What's happening is very strange,
I belong to another StackExchange!

> it's strange to identify it.

I'm indeed off-topic here in Puzzling,
It isn't always clear what I'm saying.

> Spam are off topics, which are not clear

Even though I'm often too broad,
Review it, something is flawed.

> spam message found broad sometimes, also flawed

For new users I'm a big trouble

> its trouble for new users

Oh, don't forget to add a comment,
late it's not, takes just a moment!

> usually we add comment or flagged it as spam question.

Comment: Good attempt, but it's not spam